# Find $m$ such that $m \equiv 18( mod 19)$ and $m \equiv 22(mod 23)$

Tags: number-theory

> I actually need to find a number $m$ which satisifes $m \equiv 18\,( mod\ 19)$ and $m\equiv 22\,(mod\ 23)$

I know Wilson theorem, which says $18! \equiv 18(mod\ 19)$ and $ 22! \equiv 22(mod\ 23)$. So I'm getting two distinct numbers, need to choose a single one which works for both.

Comment: Look up the Chinese Remainder theorem.  By inspection, $-1$ works.

Comment: $m>0$ and Chinese remainder will give $mod(19*23)$

Comment: **Hint** $\ \ \begin{align} 
m\equiv 18&\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\!\!\pmod{19}\\
m\equiv 22&\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\!\!\pmod{23} \end{align}  \iff 19,23\mid m+1 \iff 19\cdot 23\mid m+1\ \ $

Comment: okay that would mean $19\cdot 23$ divides $m+1$, so actually m= $19\cdot 23-1$ works.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$19|m+1$ and $23|m+1$

Let $n=m+1$, then $lcm(19,23)=437|n$

Thus n can be $437k$ for all $k \in Z$

Hence $m=437k-1$